# How to continue running a program in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have made a bash program in Ubuntu. The program is "rock, scissors paper with computer". I want to continue this program until the message "you win, bye bye".

Could anyone suggest a method for me to do this using the code below?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Welcome to play Rock, Paper, Scissors"
echo "Choose Rock(0), Paper(1), Scissors(2)"

#read players choice
read PLAYER

choices=( 0 1 2 )

#randomize the computer choice
COMPUTER=${choices[$((RANDOM%3))]}

if [[ $PLAYER = 0 && $COMPUTER = 1 ]]
    then echo "i have paper , i win";
elif [[ $PLAYER = 1 && $COMPUTER = 1 ]]
    then echo "i have paper , we draw";
elif [[ $PLAYER = 2 && $COMPUTER = 1 ]]
    then echo "i have paper , you win, bye bye";
elif [[ $PLAYER = 0 && $COMPUTER = 0 ]]
    then echo "i have rock , we draw";
elif [[ $PLAYER = 1 && $COMPUTER = 0 ]]
    then echo "i have rock , you win, bye bye";
elif [[ $PLAYER = 2 && $COMPUTER = 0 ]]
    then echo "i have rock , i win";
elif [[ $PLAYER = 0 && $COMPUTER = 2 ]]
    then echo "i have scissors, you win, bye bye";
elif [[$count = 0 && $PLAYER = 1 && $COMPUTER = 2 ]]
    then echo "i have scissors, i win";
elif [[$count = 0 && $PLAYER = 2 && $COMPUTER = 2 ]]
    then echo "i have scissors, we draw "
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole while thing in a `while true` loop and `break` out at each point where you want to finish.

Note also that there's no need for the `choices` array.

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Welcome to play Rock, Paper, Scissors"

while true
do
       echo "Choose Rock(0), Paper(1), Scissors(2)"
       #read players choice
       read PLAYER

       #randomize the computer choice

       COMPUTER=$((RANDOM%3))

       if [[ $PLAYER = 0 && $COMPUTER = 1 ]]
           then echo "i have paper , i win";
       elif [[ $PLAYER = 1 && $COMPUTER = 1 ]]
           then echo "i have paper , we draw";
       elif [[ $PLAYER = 2 && $COMPUTER = 1 ]]
           then echo "i have paper , you win, bye bye"; break
       elif [[ $PLAYER = 0 && $COMPUTER = 0 ]]
           then echo "i have rock , we draw";
       elif [[ $PLAYER = 1 && $COMPUTER = 0 ]]
           then echo "i have rock , you win, bye bye"; break
       elif [[ $PLAYER = 2 && $COMPUTER = 0 ]]
           then echo "i have rock , i win";
       elif [[ $PLAYER = 0 && $COMPUTER = 2 ]]
           then echo "i have scissors, you win, bye bye"; break
       elif [[$count = 0 && $PLAYER = 1 && $COMPUTER = 2 ]]
           then echo "i have scissors, i win";
       elif [[$count = 0 && $PLAYER = 2 && $COMPUTER = 2 ]]
           then echo "i have scissors, we draw "
       fi
done
```

Comment: i don't know 'while true~break'. can you teach its meaning to me?

Comment: `while true` will repeat the commands between `do` and `done` forever. But any `break` statement within the loop will break out and execute whatever commands come after the `done`. In this case there are no commands after the loop so the script exits.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add an infinite loop, using a `while` loop, and exit the program depending on player input. Ex:

```
#!/usr/env bash

echo "Welcome to play Rock, Paper, Scissors"

choices=( 0 1 2 )

while [ "$PLAYER" != "Q" ]; do
    echo "Choose Rock(0), Paper(1), Scissors(2), or quit (Q)"
    read PLAYER

    #randomize the computer choice
    COMPUTER=${choices[$((RANDOM%3))]}

    if   [[ "$PLAYER" = "0" && "$COMPUTER" = "1" ]]
        then echo "i have paper , i win"
    elif [[ "$PLAYER" = "1" && "$COMPUTER" = "1" ]]
        then echo "i have paper , we draw"
    elif [[ "$PLAYER" = "2" && "$COMPUTER" = "1" ]]
        then echo "i have paper , you win, bye bye"
    elif [[ "$PLAYER" = "0" && "$COMPUTER" = "0" ]]
        then echo "i have rock , we draw"
    elif [[ "$PLAYER" = "1" && "$COMPUTER" = "0" ]]
        then echo "i have rock , you win, bye bye"
    elif [[ "$PLAYER" = "2" && "$COMPUTER" = "0" ]]
        then echo "i have rock , i win"
    elif [[ "$PLAYER" = "0" && "$COMPUTER" = "2" ]]
        then echo "i have scissors, you win, bye bye"
    elif [[ "$PLAYER" = "1" && "$COMPUTER" = "2" && "$count" = "0" ]]
        then echo "i have scissors, i win"
    elif [[ "$PLAYER" = "2" && "$COMPUTER" = "2" && "$count" = "0" ]]
        then echo "i have scissors, we draw "
    fi
done
```

Comment: well, in my computer, it has an error on line 6. that said,"!= is unary operator expected" please fix it and reupload for me?

Comment: That's because `PLAYER` has not been set before being used, and so the while condition sees only `!= "Q"` which is an error.
A fix might be to set `PLAYER` to something before the loop starts. Also, I would always guard the variable with double quotes when using it in conditions, i.e. `"$PLAYER"` just in case it's not set. This should really be done in all of those `if` conditions; it's good coding practice.